# jquery button opens 2 permission dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook app, and every since adding jQuery to the code i've run into some strange behaviour.

This is my original code that works fine:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info);
            });
        }
        else {

        }
    }, {scope:'publish_stream'});
}
```

Then i added jQuery and used the click event instead:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info);
            });
        }
        else {

        }
    }, {scope:'publish_stream'});
});
```

And now two permission dialogs opens when i click the button. Why is this?

Comment: The only thing that would make sense would be the context of `this` has changed - inside the jQuery callback `this` is now the element `#button`, whereas previously it was a different object.

Comment: Have you removed the first code? Are you sure that only one element, with id #button does exist in your page?

Comment: probably you are calling the click event explicitly somewhere in your code ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably this code is running twice. You can check it with console.log() or alerts. Your original code worked, because "button.onclick = ..." overwrites the previous onlick event handler, while jQuery uses addEventListener (or attachHandler on IE), which does not remove the prevoius handler.

If so, try

```
$('#button').unbind('click').click(function() {....});
```

Comment: This seems very possible since i use `FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);` and `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);` to check user status. How can i get around this?